# How can i find the maximum gdp per population in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables countries and coutry_stats.

Countries table

| Country_id | name | country_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aruba | AW |
| 2 | Afghanistan | AF |

Country_stats table

| Country_id | year | population | gdp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1986 | 62644 | 405463417 |
| 1 | 1987 | 61833 | 487602457 |
| 1 | 1988 | 61079 | 596423607 |
| 1 | 1989 | 61032 | 695304363 |
| 1 | 1990 | 62149 | 764887117 |
| 1 | 1991 | 64622 | 872138730 |
| 2 | 1960 | 8996973 | 537777811 |
| 2 | 1961 | 9169410 | 548888895 |
| 2 | 1962 | 9351441 | 546666677 |
| 2 | 1963 | 9543205 | 751111191 |
| 2 | 1964 | 9744781 | 800000044 |
| 2 | 1965 | 9956320 | 1006666638 |

How can i find the maximum gdp / popupation along the years?

i tried

```
select 
  countries.country_id, 
  name, 
  country_code, 
  year, 
  gdp, 
  population, 
  max(gdp / population) as per_ratio 
from 
  countries JOIN country_stats on 
  countries.country_id = country_stats.country_id
where 
  countries.country_id = 1 group by name order by per_ratio;
```

but im getting this

| Country_id | name | country_code | year | gdp | population | per_ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aruba | AB | 1986 | 405463417 | 62644 | 27084.7037 |

the per_ratio is the correct maximum of this country but this is not the correct record in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would likely yield the result you're looking for - it sorts per_ratio DESC and limits that record to one.

```
SELECT
   countries.country_id, 
   name, 
   country_code, 
   year, 
   gdp, 
   population, 
   gdp / population as per_ratio 
FROM countries 
JOIN country_stats 
   on countries.country_id = country_stats.country_id 
WHERE countries.country_id = 1
ORDER BY per_ratio DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Alternatively, you could use a partition to first get the max for the country id in a CTE, and then pull in all records where max_per_ratio = per_ratio

```
WITH MAX_PER AS(
SELECT
   countries.country_id, 
   name, 
   country_code, 
   year, 
   gdp, 
   population, 
   gdp / population as per_ratio,
   MAX(gdp/population) OVER(PARTITION BY country_id) AS max_per_ratio
FROM countries 
JOIN country_stats 
   on countries.country_id = country_stats.country_id 
WHERE countries.country_id = 1)

SELECT
   country_id, 
   name, 
   country_code, 
   year, 
   gdp, 
   population, 
   per_ratio 
FROM MAX_PER
WHERE max_per_ratio = per_ratio;
```

Comment: Thanks! i guess i wasnt limit the results!

Comment: and how can i have the the maximum for every country? this one obviously limits the results to one. i need to have the records for all countries with the maximum per_ratio

Comment: The second option should do that

Comment: Thanks for the answers. can you please explain what the second query does? im not familiar with the "WITH" clause

Comment: The WITH clause is a Common Table Expression (CTE), it works similarly to a subquery. The query in the with clause sets up a column that gets the max per_ratio by country, and the main query keeps only values where the per_ratio = the max ratio